# PowerBI - Count the number of blanks for a Column Value after filtering by that column value

Tags: powerbi

I have a requirement where I am trying to count the number of blank rows for a particular column value.

For Example,
Table 1

```
ColA ColB
A     as
A
B     ab
B
B
C    
C
```

And my expected output is
Table1

```
ColA ColB output
A     as    1
A           1
B     ab    2
B           2
B           2   
C           2
C           2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of rows where `ColA` is the same and `ColB` is blank.

Try this as a calculated column:

```
output = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),
                   Table1[ColA] = EARLIER(Table1[ColA]),
                   Table1[ColB] = BLANK())
```

The `EARLIER` function refers to the earlier row context.